# C++ Indirectly Assign Array Value?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, indirection

I've got a series of arrays that I'm referencing in a large if statement for assignment below. I'd like to reference them indirectly somehow if it's possible?

```
         if (m == 1)  EleN[CorrPos] = S1N[ID];
    else if (m == 2)  EleN[CorrPos] = S2N[ID];
    else if (m == 3)  EleN[CorrPos] = S3N[ID];
    else if (m == 4)  EleN[CorrPos] = S4N[ID];
    else if (m == 5)  EleN[CorrPos] = S5N[ID];
    else if (m == 6)  EleN[CorrPos] = S6N[ID];
    else if (m == 7)  EleN[CorrPos] = S7N[ID];
    else if (m == 8)  EleN[CorrPos] = S8N[ID];
    else if (m == 9)  EleN[CorrPos] = S9N[ID];
    else if (m == 10) EleN[CorrPos] = S10N[ID];
```

Is it possible to call this indirectly as in an indirectly somehow?

EleN[CorrPos]=@"S" + m +"N[ID]"

Comment: Could you explain what you intend to do a bit more? There is no @ in C / C++. What's CorrPos? By series of arrays you mean an array of array pointers?

Comment: What is "an indirectly"?

Comment: Sorry, CorrPos is just the name of the integer index to EleN, nothing special

Comment: Goal is to find a way to avoid writing a long conditional if statement, I'm not allowed to change the S1N, S2N, etc arrays and want to know if it's possible to call them

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of pointers to the `S` arrays, then you could simply do e.g.

```
EleN[CorrPos] = S_Array[m - 1][ID];  // -1 since array-indexes are zero-based
```

Comment: A vector or map would also be options.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't I still have to set up a big conditional if statement to set up the pointer references to S1N, S2N, etc?

Comment: @NickJacobi No, you just initialize the `S_Array` (in my example) once. Like `SomeType* S_Array[10] = { S1N, S2N, ... }`